# Formatted output and fprintf

Tags: c

I wrote this small C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 FILE * fp;
 fp = fopen("data.txt","w");
 fprintf(fp,"%d",578); 
 return 0;
}
```

Then I analyzed data.txt using `xxd -b`. I was expecting that I will see the 32 bit representation of 578 instead I saw the ASCII representation of 578:

```
xxd -b data.txt
0000000: 00110101 00110111 00111000                             578
```

Why is that? How do I store the 32 bit representation of 578 (01000010 00000010 00000000 00000000) assuming little endian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fwrite`:

```
uint32_t n = 578;
fwrite(&n, sizeof n, 1, fp);
```

`fprintf` is for *formatted* output, whence the trailing `f`.

Comment: @Beginner: that one stands for "file".

Comment: Yes, I know, but from your last sentence it follows it will stand for *formatted* always, won't it?

Comment: @Beginner:  the two functions are fprintf (File Print Formatted) and fwrite (File Write).

Answer (score 3):

That's the meaning of "Formatted". You used qualifier `%d` which means "format the given value as its <strike>ASCII</strike> numeric representation *in the execution character set*, assuming the value is a signed integer".

If you want to write binary data into a file - **don't** use formatted output. Use [`fwrite`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) instead to write raw binary data.

Comment: Why does printf change to ASCII? Does the terminal expect ASCII?

Comment: Indeed, C never mentions "ASCII". "In the execution character set" would be a more appropriate description.

Comment: @Bruce: `printf` always formats its arguments for human consumption. It's not used for writing binary.

Comment: Removed the ASCII, it can indeed be whatever character set is set for the console.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look at [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/).

```
int myNum = 578;
fwrite( &myNum, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Comment: why do you link to a C++ header if tag of the question is C?

Comment: Its a good reference, and the same function is available in both C and C++.   If you want a "pure" C reference: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite

Comment: Yes it is, but I think it's confusing. Maybe you better put "pure" C reference in your answer?

Comment: No.  I picked the better reference, even if it came from a C++ site.  Quit complaining.

Comment: Both links you provided are not *references* but third party sites. This one *is* a reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html I'm quit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write raw data to a file using the standard IO facilities, you're looking for `fwrite(3)`:

```
$ cat numbers.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 578;
    long l = 578;
    float f = 5.78;
    double d = .578;
    long marker = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;


    FILE *fp = fopen("data", "w");
    fwrite(&i, sizeof i, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&marker, sizeof marker, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&l, sizeof l, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&marker, sizeof marker, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&f, sizeof f, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&marker, sizeof marker, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&d, sizeof d, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
$ make numbers
cc     numbers.c   -o numbers
$ ./numbers 
$ xxd data
0000000: 4202 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff 4202 0000  B...........B...
0000010: 0000 0000 ffff ffff ffff ffff c3f5 b840  ...............@
0000020: ffff ffff ffff ffff e5d0 22db f97e e23f  .........."..~.?
$ xxd -b data
0000000: 01000010 00000010 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111  B.....
0000006: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......
000000c: 01000010 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  B.....
0000012: 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  ......
0000018: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11000011 11110101  ......
000001e: 10111000 01000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111  .@....
0000024: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100101 11010000  ......
000002a: 00100010 11011011 11111001 01111110 11100010 00111111  "..~.?
$
```